get_total_transfer(tx_hash, receipt) function to compute the total amount transferred for each token involved in an Ethereum transaction
How can I implement the get_total_transfer(tx_hash, receipt) function to compute the total amount transferred for each token involved in an Ethereum transaction (tx), using transaction data and receipts fetched from the Infura Mainnet, and return a dictionary where each token serves as a key mapped to its corresponding total transfer amount?
I’m using the following code in Python. But it’s not working:
def get_total_transfer(tx_hash, receipt):
    # Define the ERC20 Transfer event signature and its hash
    transfer_event_signature = "Transfer(address,address,uint256)"
    transfer_event_topic = "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"

    # Dictionary to store token transfer amounts
    token_transfers = {}

    # Retrieve logs from the transaction receipt
    logs = receipt['logs']

    for log in logs:
        # Check if the log matches the Transfer event signature and topic
        if log['topics'][0] == transfer_event_topic:
            # Decode log data according to the Transfer event signature
            decoded_log = decode_abi([transfer_event_signature], log['data'])
            print(decoded_log)
            from_address = decoded_log[0]  # sender address
            to_address = decoded_log[1]    # receiver address
            value = decoded_log[2]          # token value transferred

            # Normalize addresses
            from_address = from_address.lower()
            to_address = to_address.lower()

            # Update token transfer amounts
            if from_address in token_transfers:
                token_transfers[from_address] -= value
            else:
                token_transfers[from_address] = -value

            if to_address in token_transfers:
                token_transfers[to_address] += value
            else:
                token_transfers[to_address] = value

    return token_transfers



I believe from_address and to_address should be:
from_address = log['topics'][1]
to_address = log['topics'][2]

while value should be either decoded_log or decoded_log[0] (depends on how your decoding works).
